# Magento 2.4.2 , php v8.0

Tags: magento2

I am getting an error 404[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v95El.png)

I have mostly tried everything with my reserach but nothing is working. need help.

Answer (score 0):

Copy files index.php and .htaccess from pub/static file to root folder.